# How to pass value from label in asp.net page to another page via href link

Tags: asp.net

I need to pass label value in default.aspx to default2.aspx via href link. But its not working. Here is my code.

```
<a href="Default2.aspx?val=" + Label1.Text>
```

I need to pass the label1.text value to default2.aspx. Here I am using the href link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="#" runat="server" id="hlk">
```

On Page_Load Event.

```
 hlk.href="Default2.aspx?val="+Label1.Text;
```

Answer (score -1):

Write in Default.aspx.cs`response.redirect("second.aspx?string="textbox1.text);`

//and on second page

```
string value= request.querystring["string"].tostring();
```